# Is it using "like, e.g.," seen as incorrect?

Tags: phrase-usage, questions

I'm trying to give an example for muting an Alert on a technical guide:

> An Alert should communicate clearly and as soon as its conditions
>   meet.
>
> However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary
>   noise on your notification channels like, e.g., scheduled maintenance.

I'm not sure if it is correct to use both interruptions, I've searched the terms and it doesn't seem to come together, for example here it just compares them -> https://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2010/11/grammar-workshop-ie-versus-eg-and-such-as-versus-like.html

But, it says that "e.g.= for example" and "like introduces a model, but not the exact example". So in my sentence, I would be doing the same as:

> However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary
>   noise on your notification channels (like) introducing, (e.g.) for example, scheduled maintenance.

Is it incorrect?

Comment: You should not use both *e.g.* and *for example* at the same time. That's redundant. In the example sentence, it's essentially no different than writing *for example (for example).* The same is mostly true of *(like) introducing*. Although those two words aren't nearly as similar in meaning, it is still bizarre to see them next to each other that way. (The equivalent of *like* is *such as*, not *introducing*.)

Comment: I suggest "However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary noise on your notification channels, for example during scheduled maintenance."

Comment: @JasonBassford: I can't really see that. There are many context in which ***like*** is exactly synonymous with and replaceable by *[such] **as***, and obviously ***e.g.*** can always be replaced by ***for example***. Given that there are many written instances of the sequence [***as, for example***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+for+example%22) in Google Books, it's not obvious to me we can single out OP's *specific* sequence and context as "incorrect". Maybe it's just *not universally considered idiomatic*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Are you sure you didn't misread my comment? You're essentially saying what I did.

Comment: @JasonBassford: You're right - I didn't fully digest your comment. Yeah - we both seem to be saying / implying that *most* native speakers tend to avoid this *specific* form, so it's definitely "non-idiomatic" for most of us. I'm not *quite* convinced this is because it's "tautologous", but I wouldn't argue against that line (I have no alternative line of reasoning, that's for sure! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using "*like, e.g.*" is incorrect.

In general English these expressions, among others, can be used interchangeably.

Also, *meet* would be better written in the passive voice.

> An Alert should communicate clearly and as soon as its conditions *are met*.

Here you want to describe an example item or a non-exhaustive list, hence the use of example(s) in the sentence.

> - However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary noise on your notification channels, *like* scheduled maintenance.
> - However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary noise on your notification channels, *such as* scheduled maintenance.
> - However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary noise on your notification channels, *e.g.* scheduled maintenance.
> - However, some circumstances may lead to generating unnecessary noise on your notification channels, *for example* scheduled maintenance.